# Copy rows as values separated by newline from excel to another software

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, copy-paste

im trying to copy values from excel to another software. I have my values in a single column in excel.

But any shortcut i use, the values get copied as space separated values.

Is there any way i could copy them as newline (/n) separated values, so that when i paste them in the other software (web), they come on different lines?  Any action or keyboard shortcut works.

I am using latest chrome and ms-excel on mac.

Answer (score 1):

Any time I need to manipulate text, I use [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com).

1. Copy your cells from Excel
2. Open up a new window in Sublime Text
3. Paste into Sublime Text, they will show up as separate lines
4. Hit Command+A to select all the text
5. Then copy that text and paste it into your web form.

You can probably do this in the default Notes app on the Mac, but where's the fun in that? :)